# How can a deduced template type be viewed in the Xcode debugger?

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11, templates, type-deduction

How can a deduced template type be viewed in the Xcode debugger?

Using examples from Item 1 in Meyers' Effective Modern C++ (2015), notice how the value of the variable, and its type, are visible in Xcode's "variables view," but there's no way to see the resulting deduction of the variable T.

Is it possible to see the deduced type of T in the Xcode debugger?

My boss gave me `typeId`, as shown below, but I would like to see the type directly in the debugger. Additionally, this command yields inconsistend results across IDEs; e.g., Xcode outputs "i" for an int, while Visual Studio outputs "int."

Full executable and output shown below. Thx, Keith :^)

**Xcode Screenshot**

[image: Xcode type deduction]

**Minimal, complete, and verifiable example:**

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
int case1a(T& param) {
    return param;
}
template <typename T>
int case1b(const T& param) {
    std::cout << "Type ID   : " << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Type param: " << typeid(param).name() << std::endl;
    return param;
}
template <typename T>
int case2(T&& param) {
    return param;
}
template <typename T>
int case3(T param) {
    return param;
}
int main() {

    int a(23);
    const int ar(a);
    const int & car = a;

    float b(7.);
    std::cout << "case1a(a): " << case1a(a) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "case1a(ar): " << case1a(ar) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "case1a(car): " << case1a(car) << std::endl;

    std::cout << "case1b(a): " << case1b(a) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "case1b(ar): " << case1b(ar) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "case1b(car): " << case1b(car) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "case1b(b): " << case1b(b) << std::endl;

    std::cout << "case2(a): " << case2(a) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "case2(ar): " << case2(ar) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "case2(car): " << case2(car) << std::endl;

    std::cout << "case3(a): " << case3(a) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "case3(ar): " << case3(ar) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "case3(car): " << case3(car) << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
case1a(a): 23
case1a(ar): 23
case1a(car): 23
case1b(a): Type ID   : i
Type param: i
23
case1b(ar): Type ID   : i
Type param: i
23
case1b(car): Type ID   : i
Type param: i
23
case1b(b): Type ID   : f
Type param: f
7
case2(a): 23
case2(ar): 23
case2(car): 23
case3(a): 23
case3(ar): 23
case3(car): 23

Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Comment: what IDE you use is almost completely irrelevant for the output of your code (eg what `typeid.name` returns). It is the compiler that compiles your code and you can use the same compiler in different IDEs or different compilers in the same IDE

Comment: Agreed; so, irrespective of compiler, how can the deduced template type be viewed in Xcode?

Comment: i dont really understand the question. In the screenshot you have the type, no?

Comment: btw imho the `type-deduction` tag is correctly used here but its text is a bit unexpected: "...determine the datatype of a class or a variable at **runtime**"

Comment: @tobi303 two types are deduced: that for the template "T" in this example, and the type of the parameter.

Comment: you mean eg `param` is type `T&&` then what is `T` ? You could instantiate a second template inside the function whose parameter is only `T`. Actually you are already doing this by calling `typeid(T).name()`. Sorry I cant help you on this as I am not familiar with Xcode. Btw the type of the parameter has not to be deduced, but it is only `T` that is deduced based on the type of the parameter you pass